# Filtering coordinates based on distance from a point

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two arrays say:

```
A = np.array([[ 1.  ,  1.  ,  0.5 ],
              [ 2.  ,  2.  ,  0.7 ],
              [ 3.  ,  4.  ,  1.2 ],
              [ 4.  ,  3.  ,  2.33],
              [ 1.  ,  2.  ,  0.5 ],
              [ 6.  ,  5.  ,  0.3 ],
              [ 4.  ,  5.  ,  1.2 ],
              [ 5.  ,  5.  ,  1.5 ]])

B = np.array([2,1])
```

I would want to find all values of `A` which are not within a radius of 2 from `B`.

My answer should be:

```
C = [[3,4,1.2],[4,3,2.33],[6,5,0.3],[4,5,1.2],[5,5,1.5]]
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

What I have tried is:

```
radius = 2
C.append(np.extract((cdist(A[:, :2], B[np.newaxis]) > radius), A))
```

But I realized that `np.extract` flattens `A` and i dont get what i is expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `R` be the radius here. We would have few methods to solve it, as discussed next.

**Approach #1 :** Using [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

A[(cdist(A[:,:2],B[None]) > R).ravel()]
```

**Approach #2 :** Using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
d = A[:,:2] - B
out = A[np.einsum('ij,ij->i', d,d) > R**2]
```

**Approach #3 :** Using [`np.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) -

```
A[np.linalg.norm(A[:,:2] - B, axis=1) > R]
```

**Approach #4 :** Using `matrix-multiplication` with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
A[(A[:,:2]**2).sum(1) + (B**2).sum() - 2*A[:,:2].dot(B) > R**2]
```

**Approach #5 :** Using a combination of `einsum` and `matrix-multiplication` -

```
A[np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A[:,:2],A[:,:2]) + B.dot(B) - 2*A[:,:2].dot(B) > R**2]
```

**Approach #6 :** Using `broadcasting` -

```
A[((A[:,:2] - B)**2).sum(1) > R**2]
```

Hence, to get the points within radius `R` simply replace `>` with `<` in the above mentioned solutions.

Comment: it'll be nice to see timing on those ones

Answer (score 3):

Another useful approach not mentioned by @Divakar is to use a [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html):

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# Find indices of points within radius
radius = 2
indices = cKDTree(A[:, :2]).query_ball_point(B, radius)

# Construct a mask over these points
mask = np.zeros(len(A), dtype=bool)
mask[indices] = True

# Extract values not among the nearest neighbors
A[~mask]
```

The primary benefit is that it will be much faster than any direct approach as the size of the array increases, because the data structure avoids computing a distance for every point in `A`.