# Find minimum distances between groups of points in 2D (fast and not too memory consuming)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have two sets of points in 2D `A` and `B` and I need to find the minimum distance for each point in `A`, to a point in `B`. So far I've been using SciPy's [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) with the code below

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def ABdist(A, B):
    # Distance to all points in B, for each point in A.
    dist = cdist(A, B, 'euclidean')
    # Indexes to minimum distances.
    min_dist_idx = np.argmin(dist, axis=1)
    # Store only the minimum distances for each point in A, to a point in B.
    min_dists = [dist[i][md_idx] for i, md_idx in enumerate(min_dist_idx)]

    return min_dist_idx, min_dists

N = 10000
A = np.random.uniform(0., 5000., (N, 2))
B = np.random.uniform(0., 5000., (N, 2))

min_dist_idx, min_dists = ABdist(A, B)
```

which works just fine for smallish values of `N`. But now the lengths of the sets have increased from `N=10000` to `N=35000` and I'm running into a

```
    dm = np.zeros((mA, mB), dtype=np.double)
MemoryError
```

I know I can replace `cdist` with a for loop that keeps only the minimum distance (and the index) for each point in `A` to each point in `B`, as that is all I need. I don't need the full `AxB` distance matrix. But I've been using `cdist` precisely because it is fast.

Is there a way to replace `cdist` with an implementation that is (almost?) as fast, but that does not take that much memory?

Comment: If you divide one of the matrices in chuncks and concatenate the results back together, you can keep using `cdist`

Comment: That sounds quite reasonable actually. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best approach will involve using a data structure specially designed for nearest neighbor search, such as a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). For example, SciPy's [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) allows you to solve the problem this way:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
min_dists, min_dist_idx = cKDTree(B).query(A, 1)
```

The result is much more efficient than any approach based on broadcasting, both in terms of computation and memory use.

For example, even with 1,000,000 points, the computation does not run out of memory, and takes only a few seconds on my laptop:

```
N = 1000000
A = np.random.uniform(0., 5000., (N, 2))
B = np.random.uniform(0., 5000., (N, 2))

%timeit cKDTree(B).query(A, 1)
# 3.25 s ± 17.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Yup! Pretty efficient.

Comment: **Amazing** answer Jake. Not only does this not consume all my memory, it is also ~250X faster than my original approach and ~160X faster than splitting the `A` set (for N=25000). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to maximize compute versus memory ratio here. The output is of length `N`, one index and distance for each pt in `A`. We could reduce it to one loop with one output element per iteration and this will process through all `B` pts per iteration, which is bringing in the high compute ratio.

Thus, leveraging `einsum` and `matrix-multiplication` inspired from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755868/), for each point `pt` in `A`, we would get the squared euclidean distances, like so -

```
for pt in A:
    d = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',B,B) + pt.dot(pt) - 2*B.dot(pt)
```

Thus, generalizing it cover all points in `A` and pre-computing `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',B,B)`, we would have an implementation like so -

```
min_idx = np.empty(N, dtype=int)
min_dist = np.empty(N)
Bsqsum = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',B,B) 
for i,pt in enumerate(A):
    d = Bsqsum + pt.dot(pt) - 2*B.dot(pt)
    min_idx[i] = d.argmin()
    min_dist[i] = d[min_idx[i]]
min_dist = np.sqrt(min_dist)
```

#### Working in chunks

Now, a fully vectorized solution would be -

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i',B,B)[:,None] + np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,A) - 2*B.dot(A.T)
```

So, to work in chunks, we would slice out rows off `A` and to do so would be easier to simply reshape to `3D`, like so -

```
chunk_size= 100 # Edit this as per memory setup available
                # More means more memory needed
A.shape = (A.shape[0]//chunk_size, chunk_size,-1)

min_idx = np.empty((N//chunk_size, chunk_size), dtype=int)
min_dist = np.empty((N//chunk_size, chunk_size))

Bsqsum = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',B,B)[:,None]
r = np.arange(chunk_size)
for i,chnk in enumerate(A):
    d = Bsqsum + np.einsum('ij,ij->i',chnk,chnk) - 2*B.dot(chnk.T)
    idx = d.argmin(0)
    min_idx[i] = idx
    min_dist[i] = d[idx,r]
min_dist = np.sqrt(min_dist)

min_idx.shape = (N,)
min_dist.shape = (N,)
A.shape = (N,-1)
```

Comment: Your answers are always a chance to learn something new Divakar, thanks! I've tried the first implementation of your code (before *If memory permits...*) and it is substantially slower than splitting the `A` array. The last implementation sadly fails again with a `MemoryError`.

Comment: @Gabriel Yeah, figured that would have caused mem error. Check out the edits.

Comment: Even using 10000 chunks (which eats up almost all my RAM) this is still rather slow.

Comment: @Gabriel Yeah, `cKDTree` should be much better as suggested in the other post.